# where to put the properties file in an eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, properties-file

Please tell me where exactly do i put my .properties file in my eclipse project. Do I make a separate folder for it ?
I want to put it in such a way that I will be able to distribute my project easily in JAR form.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I want to put the properties file in such a way that it can be easily edited later, on any OS.

Comment: That's one way.  The key thing is: How does your code access it?  You can't use a FileInputStream; you need to use getResourceAsStream() to get it from the classpath using the class loader.

Comment: If you want easily to edit it later, you'll need to put the file outside the jar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The approach I use in order to be able to **easily change configuration without redeployment**.

One version of the property file (with the defaults) in the root of your project, I always let it in the application package (foo.bar.myapp). I load the default one with `getResourceAsStream("/foo/bar/myapp/config.properties")` or like in the sample relative to the class package.

And additionally I ready a system property:

```
String configFileLocation = System.getProperty("config");
```

And just override the default with the properties read from the config file passed as property.

For instance:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("mydefault.properties"));

System.out.println("default loaded: " + props);

String configFile = System.getProperty("config");
if (configFile != null) {
    props.load(new FileInputStream(configFile));
    System.out.println("custom config loaded from " + configFile);
}

System.out.println("custom override: " + props);
```

This would load first your resource stored under your project in `foo.bar` package named `mydefault.properties`, and after it if system property `config` is configured it will load override the loaded properties with the one the the referred path.

The system property can be set using `-D` parameter, in this case would be something like: `java -Dconfig=/home/user/custom.properties foo.bar.Main`. Or if you are in a web application (Tomcat for instance) you can set this property using `CATALINA_OPTS`.

Comment: Not a good idea to hard code package names into strings in your code IMHO. Better to use the class's getResourceAsStream with a simple (unqualified) name and it will automagically prepend the package path! All IMHO of course - HTH

Comment: @davidfrancis: thanks for your suggestion I will change the sample

Answer (score 0):

`src/main/resource` would be an ideal choice.